# Do any Christian denominations consider Pontius Pilate as a saint?

Tags: denomination-survey, tradition, canonization, pontius-pilate

Do any Christian denominations consider Pontius Pilate a recognized saint, either by canonization or through tradition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by the:

- [Ethiopian Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_Orthodox_Tewahedo_Church) with a feast day on June 19
- [Coptic Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_Church) with a feast day of June 25

Why?

The above churches believed that Pilate became Christian, was baptized, and even tried to save St. Stephen from being executed, and built a church in honor of Stephen.

*Source: [Wikipedia on Pontius Pilate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontius_Pilate)*

See also: [Pontius Pilate, a saint?](https://www.thecompassnews.org/2019/04/pontius-pilate-a-saint/)